# How to hide row when value of one of the cell in row is "yes"?

Tags: javascript, hide, google-sheets

I have this function

```
function HideRow()
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  var datarange = s.hideRows(2);//this will hide Column B
}
```

But i don't know how to use this function `HideRows()` with checking value of one of the cell in the row to "yes". Could someone explain me?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `QUERY` formula to achieve this.

Please post a Sheet with Dummy Data so we can show you how to use it.

In the meantime, as a generic example:

```
=Query(A:Z; "Select A,B,C...Z Where X='YES'";1)
```

**A:Z** is the range

**Select A,B,C...Z** are the columns for the rows you wish to hide

**WHERE X='YES'** this is the condition that will hide the row.

Cheers,